# AWS dynamodb export using data pipeline not working for eu-north-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I've prepared data pipeline (in eu-west-1 region) based on template that would export dynamodb table to S3. My table is located in eu-north-1 region, but when putting that under the parameter myDDBRegion I get the following error:

```
Object:EmrClusterForBackup
ERROR: 'region' has invalid value 'eu-north-1' It can have only one of the following values: [ap-south-1, eu-west-3, eu-west-2, eu-west-1, ap-northeast-2, ap-northeast-1, sa-east-1, ca-central-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-southeast-2, us-iso-east-1, eu-central-1, us-east-1, us-east-2, us-west-1, us-west-2]
```

Is this a non supported region to export data from ? If so, how do I accomplish exporting data from this table ?

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline mahy internally use EMR to convert data and store to target data store

And as per [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-manage-region.html), eu-north-1 is not supported for data pipeline as it can't launch EMR/EC2 though eu-north-1 actually supports EMR service